# Deleted /etc/pam.d/common

Tags: permissions, sudo, data-recovery, pam

I deleted all `common-*` files in `/etc/pam.d` folder and now I am locked out.  I am running Ubuntu 14.04.  I did backup all these files in a folder inside `pam.d` but now I can't even move them.  If I try, I get a permission error.  If I add sudo, I get this error:

```
sudo: unable to initialize PAM: No such file or directory
```

Here are things I tried and failed:

- `sudo pam-auth-update --force` (get above error)
- Went into recovery mode and ran "Repair broken packages"
- Went to recovery mode, and chose 'root - Drop to root shell prompt'.  When I hit enter, I get this:

  ```
  Give root password for maintenance. (or type Control-D to continue)**
  ```

I never set any password for the root account and I believe it might be disabled.  I get access to the console via the web and do not have access physically.

I did tons of searching on Google and almost all point to using LiveCD which is not an option for me.  Is there anything else I can do to fix it?

Comment: Whomever the admin is will have to either boot from a LiveCD/LiveUSB or reinstall. If you don't have root or physical access to the machine then there's nothing that you can do.

Comment: Ok, thanks.  Now I can rebuild in peace knowing there are no other options.  I will add pam.d to my do not delete list  :)

Answer (score 1):

Since the `common-*` files are not there you cannot run `sudo`

Therefore you must boot to `single user mode` the link below has great instructions

[Boot to single user mode](https://askubuntu.com/questions/132965/how-do-i-boot-into-single-user-mode-from-grub#132983)

Once you are boot up you will have a root shell.

Comment: I re-read this and this only works if you can bounce the machine so sorry that this doesn't help you specifically but hope it helps another who deleted the PAM configuration files.

Answer (score -1):

If your web console has access to edit Grub, you can change the `init=` portion of the boot string to: `init=/bin/bash`

That will drop you directly into a bash shell.

From there you'll need to remount the system from read-only to read-write.

`mount -o remount,rw /`

Once the system is read-write, you can restore your files.

Also while there, if you wish, you can set the root password.

Comment: If he doesn't have root access then it's highly unlikely that he can edit `grub`.

Comment: He can't edit the grub configuration on the filesystem - but he may be able to edit the grub entry on boot.

Comment: How can he edit it on boot when he doesn't have root or physical access?

Comment: @Nasir Riley: You don't need root to edit the grub entry on boot (although a username/password  combination can be set separately for it).  The root account on the linux system is completely irrelevant to grub's boot operations.  Additionally, web consoles typically do show the boot-loader - this is confirmed since the user says the can get into "Recovery Mode" which is typically an option selected in the boot-loader.

Comment: He would have to drop into a shell to edit `grub`. He has already stated that he is prompted for a root password when he tries to do that. Your suggestion doesn't work.

Comment: Grub has a built-in editor just for this scenario. [See here.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19486/how-do-i-add-a-kernel-boot-parameter) and [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/KernelBootParameters).  Also he said he was prompted for root after he chose RECOVERY MODE (essentially single-user mode). Recovery Mode and Single user mode both require root password - changing the boot string to `init=/bin/bash` will not require root password.

Comment: @Nasir Riley: [This Arch linux wiki entry](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/reset_root_password#Using_GRUB_to_invoke_bash) covers the process which will work with any normal linux distribution.  I've done this multiple times on RHEL/CentOS to recover from an unknown root password or a bad grub configuration.

Comment: That still doesn't matter. He would still need to restore the files from somewhere such as a LiveUSB and he can't do that as he doesn't have physical acces which he has already stated. Editing `grub` wouldn't help him.

Comment: He restores from the backups he made on the local filesystem.  You edit grub to **boot directly into bash on the local system.**  This is why you can update the root password on the local system this way.  Instead of calling the init process, it calls a bash process and drops you directly into a root shell (without needing to authenticate).

Comment: If that were possible then he'd have already done it. Either he isn't telling us everything or he's already tried and failed. It's also possible that he deleted more than just the `common` files and those backups don't exist. Either way, your suggestion assumes that he's able to certain things and the fact that he hasn't responded in either the negative or affirmative brings that into doubt. It's unlikely that he has access to edit `grub` on boot via the web console he's using.

Comment: Or he simply didn't know that way existed - just like you didn't.  The user also explicitly said they took backups but just couldn't restore due to lack of root.  The user probably hasn't come back because you incorrectly told him that the LiveCD and physical access was the only solution.

Comment: I did know as I've edited `grub` to get into recovery and single user mode plenty of times. That brings me back to my original point which is that he probably isn't able to do it as that would be the first thing to come up during research. You have to remember that it only works if he can edit `grub` during boot which all things considered, he probably can't. In his case, I didn't incorrectly tell him anything. Perhaps you shouldn't post an answer with a huge assumption in it or you could just ask first.

Comment: You should stop assuming what people do and don't know and the configurations they're working with.  If you had known about setting the `init` parameter in the kernel, you would have asked about it and I wouldn't have had to spend the last 6 posts explaining it to you.  If you have anything else to say, you can chat me. As it is now, there's nothing productive left to say.

Comment: You didn't need to explain anything to me. Did you miss the part where I said I've done it a million times? Bottom line, it would have been better to ask him in a comment rather than post an answer that assumes things. If you had done that then maybe you wouldn't have felt the need to go off into a tangent explaining something that wasn't needed.